# Returning multiple values from function (undefined) jQuery/ifelse

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-value

I tried to look for an answer before, however, I got stuck.

I'm trying to get multiple values out of the function. Values   depend on some other parameters the user chooses. So, within the function from which I  am trying to extract multiple values and use it later, each value goes through a test (if / else) and depending on the result/choosen options gets an accurate value.

Why am i getting undefined?

The concept would look like this:

```js
function countries() {

  var countrieslist;
  var countriesIDs;

  if ($("#1").is("checked") && !$("#2").is("checked")) {
    var countrieslist = $("[for='1']").text();
  } else if ($("#1").is("checked") && $("#2").is("checked")) {
    var countrieslist = $("[for='1']").text() + " and " + $("[for='2']").text();
  } else if (!$("#1").is("checked") && $("#2").is("checked")) {
    var countrieslist = $("[for='2']").text();
  }

  if ($("#1").is("checked") && !$("#2").is("checked")) {
    var countriesIDs = $("[for='1']").text();
  } else if ($("#1").is("checked") && $("#2").is("checked")) {
    var countriesIDs = $("[for='1']").text() + " and " + $("[for='1']").text();
  } else if (!$("#1").is("checked") && $("#2").is("checked")) {
    var countriesIDs = $("[for='2']").text();
  }
  /* 
  Works when i declare these variables manually: 
        var countrieslist = "countrieslist--- test";
        var countriesIDs = "countriesIDs--- test";
*/

  return {
    countrieslist,
    countriesIDs
  }

}
cvalues = countries();


$("#1,#2").change(function() {

  $(".countrieslist").text(cvalues.countrieslist)
  $(".countriesIDs").text(cvalues.countriesIDs)
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.col {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="card text-dark mb-3" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="card-header" style="border-color:none;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.03)">Countries</div>
        <div class="card-body ps-2 pe-2">

          <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="1" autocomplete="off">
          <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mb-1" for="1">country1</label>

          <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="2" autocomplete="off">
          <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mb-1" for="2">country2</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      Countrieslist:
      <div class="alert alert-success countrieslist" role="alert">
      </div>
      CountriesIDs:
      <div class="alert alert-success countriesIDs" role="alert">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Same code on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ribosed/a132okf5/44/

Thank you

Comment: You only need to declare the variables once, not every time you assign them.

Comment: Don't redefine the variables using the `var` keyword inside of your blocks.

Comment: You're calling `countries()` when the page is first loaded, not when the user changes the checkboxes.

Comment: Move `cvalues = countries();` into the `.change()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tought when you call cvalues.countrieslist you actually, by default, call  countries() and its valuje countieslist.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone find this usefull this is the working code (for me):

```js
function countries() {
      
      var countrieslist;
      var countriesIDs;
      
        if($("#1").is(":checked") && !$("#2").is(":checked")) { 
           countrieslist = $("[for='1']").text();
          }
     else if($("#1").is(":checked") && $("#2").is(":checked")) { 
             countrieslist = $("[for='1']").text() + " and " + $("[for='2']").text() ;
      }
   else if(!$("#1").is(":checked") && $("#2").is(":checked")) { 
            countrieslist = $("[for='2']").text();
      }
      
       if($("#1").is(":checked") && !$("#2").is(":checked")) { 
           countriesIDs = $("#1").attr("id");
          }
     else if($("#1").is(":checked") && $("#2").is(":checked")) { 
            countriesIDs = $("#1").attr("id") + " and " + $("#2").attr("id");
      }
   else if(!$("#1").is(":checked") && $("#2").is(":checked")) { 
            countriesIDs = $("#2").attr("id");
      }

 
 return {countrieslist, countriesIDs}
 
}



$( "#1,#2" ).change(function () {    
cvalues = countries();
$(".countrieslist").text(cvalues.countrieslist)
$(".countriesIDs").text(cvalues.countriesIDs)
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.col {

  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
 
 <div class="card text-dark mb-3" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<div class="card-header" style="border-color:none;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.03)">Countries</div>
  <div class="card-body ps-2 pe-2">
  
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="1" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mb-1" for="1">country1</label>
    
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mb-1" for="2">country2</label> 
  </div> 
</div>

 Countrieslist:
<div class="alert alert-success countrieslist" role="alert">
</div> 
 CountriesIDs:
<div class="alert alert-success countriesIDs" role="alert">
</div> 
 
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```